# Materialize the subscription status

Tags: rx-java

Is there any operator in RxJava to materialize the subsciption status? I want to get notification when an observable subscribed and unsubscribed.

Only way I know is creating a PublishSubject and sending events to subject by using doOnSubscribe and doOnUnsubscribe operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Subscriber and use TestSubscriber which allow you to  wait until Subscriber is unsubscribe, or to know the current state.

```
        @Test
public void testIntervalObservable() {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.interval(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                          .map(time -> "item emitted\n")
                                          .subscribe(System.out::print);
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```